# How to pass to a session the result of a search. The result could be an object or many objects

Tags: django, session

how to pass multiple objects to a session?

```
fil = Enseignant.objects.filter(matricule_enseignant=identifiant).values_list('niveau__filiere__nom_fiiere', flat=True)
request.session = #?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing a list, then simply do it like this:

```
fil = Enseignant.objects.filter(matricule_enseignant=identifiant).values_list('niveau__filiere__nom_fiiere', flat=True)
request.session['fil_ids'] = list(fil)
```

And access it elsewhere like this:

```
fil_ids = request.session.get('fil_ids')
Enseignant.objects.filter(niveau__filiere__nom_fiiere__in=fil_ids)
```